# Что за бред в учебнике?

Tags: java

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Читаю в интернете учебник по Java и столкнулся с непонятной ерундой.
Начальный код я пропустил. Почему тут int названа числом? ведь так нельзя делать ... запустил на компиляторе eclipse и он выдал ошибку. Чего я не понимаю?

Comment: ...или `l`, в некоторых шрифтах она похожа на `1`.

Comment: Скорее всего, просто буква L, поэтому и не рекомендуется ее использовать при именовании

Comment: Нет, это именно 1.. Там далее есть примеры где "double 1 = d * pi" также переменная называется числом...

Comment: А вы прикрепите фото в хорошем качестве) и мы посмотрим...... но вопрос бестолковый и никому не нужный имхо.... в смысле я б закрыл)

Comment: Учебник... с кодом не в моноширинном шрифте... знаете, после этого можно ожидать чего угодно :)

Comment: Прикрепил фото...Вообщем это ошибка как я понял) тут даже "Int 12 =  585;" есть....

Comment: @АлексейШиманский: данный вопрос является хорошей иллюстрацией почему не нужно `l` использовать как имя переменной и одним этим уже является полезным.

Comment: @jfs Я согласен, что об этом надо как-то людям рассказать. Хотел в ответе это упомянуть.....Но эта тема никому больше не поможет, увы... Как и большинство других на ресурсе. Т.к. все равно поиском никто не пользуется предварительно. Все тупо сразу жмут задать вопрос, будто это возникло только у них и впервые в жизни людей...кататак......

Comment: @АлексейШиманский: для этого дубликаты существуют, чтобы по сто раз одно и то же не объяснять и обновлять ответы только в одном месте, если необходимо.

Comment: @jfs ага, расскажите это в тысячах одинаковых тем без отметки дубликат.... но это уже оффтоп

Comment: @АлексейШиманский: если вы знаете о дубликате этого вопроса, приведите ссылку (проголосуйте за закрытие как копии).

Answer (score 11):

В комментарий не уместилась ссылка поэтому пишу как ответ

Вы прикрепили скрин со страницы сайта .. скорее всего вот этого http://java-study.ru/samouchitel/9-tipydannyh  ... что означает что сделан скрин с книги некорректно... а вот книга: [смотреть тут](https://books.google.ru/books?id=-Y-h0GoYIsMC&pg=PA30&lpg=PA30&dq=java+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80+%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F+%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%85+%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2+%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85&source=bl&ots=I-YFdXLyGj&sig=c-nAt44GlxoyYY9OqtOWob_3zIY&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiwwLSsy-rJAhXkg3IKHUJkAWYQ6AEILDAD#v=onepage&q=java%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%20%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85&f=false)  **страница 30**  как мы все сказали выше - это строчная буква "L"